# Deleting a dynamically allocated Array of Pairs throwing invalid address error

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-management

I have a very curious problem. I have a custom class `Set`, and a custom class `Map` (I have to recreate the standard library implementations for a class). In my map class, I create an array of `pair<string, Set<string>>`. But, when I expand my array of values and re-hash the values, I want to delete my old array. But, Whenever (and wherever in my code...) I try to, I get a `Invalid address specified to RtlValidateHeap` error. This happens even when the delete call is on the line after my `new[]` statement.

I have private class variable I call `pair<string, Set<string>> *values;`. Then in my constructor I do the following.

```
values = new pair<string, Set<string>>[tableSize];
```

Then when I got to delete values in a member function it threw the invalid address error. The code is below - I swap `newValues`, and `values`, then `delete newValues` in the `reallocate()` function. That is where the error is thrown

Node: the map is functioning perfectly. I can hash, store, and recall values without any errors.

Expanded Code:

```
template<>
class Map<std::string, Set<string>> : public MapInterface<string,Set<string>>{
public:

Map() {
    numItems = 0;
    tableSize = BonusHashTableSize;
    values = new pair<string, Set<string>>[tableSize];
    for (int i = 0; i < tableSize; ++i) {
        values[i].first = "";
    }
};

~Map() {
    for (int i = 0; i < tableSize; ++i) {
        if (values[i].first != "") {
            values[i].second.clear();
        }
    }
    delete[] values;
};


void reallocate() {
    tableSize *= 2;
    pair<string, Set<string>> *newValues = new pair<string, Set<string>>[tableSize];
    for (int i = 0; i < tableSize; ++i) {
        newValues[i].first = "";
        newValues[i].second = Set<string>();
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < tableSize / 2; ++i) {
        if (values[i].first != "") {
            int newIndex = rehash(newValues, values[i].first);
            newValues[newIndex].first = values[i].first;
            newValues[newIndex].second = values[i].second;
            Set<string> test = newValues[newIndex].second;
        }
    }
    std::swap(values, newValues);
    delete[] newValues;

//member functions

private:
pair<string, Set<string>> *values;
int tableSize;
int numItems;
};
```

Comment: You need to use `delete[] values` just like you are in the destructor.

Comment: Thanks - that worked for deleting values right after declaration, but it still throws an error later in my code

Comment: What do you believe you have `delete values` in the constructor for? You allocate an array, then, inexplicably, delete it right away (incorrectly, to boot), and then dereference the now-dangling pointer, whereupon your program exhibits undefined behavior.

Comment: `delete values;` in the constructor does not make sense! You should not delete value at that point as you use it afterward which is undefined behavior as using `delete` instead of `delete[]`. **Why are you writing such code?** Also why are you doing manual array allocation and deletion instead of using `std::vector`.

Comment: Your `reallocate` also leaves `values` a dangling pointer. Drop `toDelete`, just `swap(values, newValues)`

Comment: @chargerstriker *the map is functioning perfectly.* -- It is not functioning perfectly -- it is severely broken.  Why aren't you simply using `std::vector<std::pair<std::string, Set<string>>> values;`, thus eliminating 90% or more of the code you have written already?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Wish I could - This is part of an assignment for  a college course - We have to design all the data structures we use. We arent allowed to use any of the standard library containers..

Comment: Did nobody notice the delete call in the constructor just after the new? And then trying to use the deleted memory location?

Comment: I've since edited my answer

Comment: @chargerstriker -- *Wish I could - This is part of an assignment for a college course* -- Nothing stopped you from creating your own vector class.  You're using templates already -- creating a simple vector class and then using that class in your hash table class would have made more sense.  As a matter of fact, it seems nonsensical to me that you were not assigned to create a dynamic array / vector class *before* trying to implement a map class. or if you have done this, not reuse that class in this assignment.

Comment: @chargerstriker -- [Example of a simple vector class](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1c3c009ea709eefd).  Something like this should have been written, thus abstracting away the dynamic array stuff that is shoe-horned into your current code, causing you all sorts of issues.

Comment: Rule of 5/3/0 seems not respected.

Answer (score -1):

Remove delete values from constructor. What is the purpose of allocation if you are just going to delete in the next line? And also you are using the deleted memory in the next for loop block.

Since you have deleted it here , it will cause invalid memory access error anywhere else because you are trying to delete already deleted memory location.

Comment: sorry that was a typo - its fixed now